# Create One Time Scheduled Job, Run When Others Not Running

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, jobs, job-scheduling

I want to create a Scheduled Job in Oracle11g Express.
I am new to Job Scheduling and my search so far points to chains but as I want to create a Job out of a function that runs irregulary at a yet unknown date I believe that Chains aren't working for my case.

The Job will be created when a Procedure finishes, which determines its Scheduled Date X.

The Job will perform some critical changes which is why I don't want it to start  while other regular scheduled jobs are running.
I want it to wait until the other jobs finish.

I only want to have it run once and than drop the job.

Is there some good practice for this case or some Option I have missed?

Comment: At the point where you create your job, you could check to see if any other jobs are running first before creating your job. To be extra sure, you could disable the other jobs, create and run your job and at the end of the job, enable the other jobs.

Comment: But the Job will be scheduled to run at a date in the future.
Like I run my function now and than it wants to schedule the job for the 15.11.2018 00:00:00. I want it to start asap at that date but not while some other job is running.

Comment: Ok, so put the check in the job so that it doesn't execute its logic until all the other jobs are not running/disabled.

Comment: Does a Loop that checks the status of the other jobs to wait for their execution work? I was unsure if that was the only way or if I just overlooked some settings on the job itself.
SELECT count(*) FROM DBA_SCHEDULER_JOBS WHERE OWNER = :OWNER AND STATE <> 'RUNNING';
This would suffice than?

Comment: It should do the trick, yes.